# RichFaces rich:panelMenu from RF demo causes error

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I've got the RichFaces demo [panelMenu source](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/panelMenu.jsf?tab=usage&cid=3875978) verbatim in an index.jsp page.  As the demo doesn't supply any backing bean code to support this source, I created these methods in `panelMenu.java`:

```
public void updateCurrent(String n) {
    logger.info("updateCurrent called with " + n);
    setCurrent(n);
}

public String getCurrent() {
    return current;
}

public void setCurrent(String c) {
    current = c;
}
```

When I run this, navigating the menu is fine, but selecting an item to output the selected element text in a box to the right of the menu causes an error:

```
WARNING: Error calling action method of component with id form:j_id_jsp_920730595_6
javax.faces.FacesException: Error calling action method of component with id form:j_id_jsp_920730595_6
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:72)
```

...

```
Caused by: javax.faces.el.MethodNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodNotFoundException: /index.jsp(27,12) '#{panelMenu.updateCurrent}' Method not found: MyClient.panelMenu@2966a5.updateCurrent()
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:92)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:57)
    ... 28 more
```

Can anyone tell me why? (Tomcat 6, RichFaces 3.3.2 SR1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method must not have any arguments. It should look like this (copied from the demo app sources):

```
public String updateCurrent() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    setCurrent((String) context.getExternalContext()
         .getRequestParameterMap().get("current"));
    return null;
}
```

`<f:param>` doesn't add method arguments. It adds request parameters.

The sources can be checked-out from http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/richfaces/tags/3.3.1.GA/samples/richfaces-demo

Comment: @Bozho - can you give me an exact link to that source? The method setCurrent needs copying in too.

Comment: @Bozho, I don't understand the part of your answer which refers to `f:param`. How is it relevant?

Comment: `setCurrent` is just a simple setter. The sources can be downloaded from http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/download/stable.html (-examples)

Comment: `<f:param name="current" value="Item 1.1"/>` is in the code from the example you linked!

Comment: @Bozho: Ref `f:param`, I now understand what you meant. Thanks