# RichFaces rich:panelMenu stops working when a4j:include'd

Tags: java, richfaces

From [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335058/richfaces-richpanelmenu-from-rf-demo-causes-error), I have noticed that when I move a `rich:panelMenu` (which works fine when in an `index.jsp` page) into `another.jsp` and then include that in `index.jsp` using an `a4j:include` tag, the `rich:panelMenu` functionality stops working.

Is this a bug?

**EDIT 1**

In response to code and after some isolation testing, the problem appears to stem from a coexistence of a `rich:dataTable` in another tab of a `rich:tabPanel` from the panelMenu.

If my `index.jsp` contains a default simple panelMenu using demo code (inc in the bean) it works as expected:

```
<f:view>
    <rich:page pageTitle="title" markupType="xhtml">
        <h:outputText id="setup" value="#{MyBacking.setup}" />
        <rich:toolBar height="35" itemSeparator="line">
            <rich:toolBarGroup location="left">
                <a4j:form>
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="panel">
                        <h:outputText style="text-align: center" value="Node Select " />
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="nodes" value="#{MyBacking.chosenNode}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{MyBacking.nodes}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                        <a4j:commandButton value="Retrieve"
                            reRender="panel,contentPanel"
                            onclick="this.disabled=true" oncomplete="this.disabled=false" />
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                </a4j:form>
            </rich:toolBarGroup>
        </rich:toolBar>
<!-- added start -->
        <h:form id="form">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%">
                <rich:panelMenu style="width:200px" mode="ajax"
                    iconExpandedGroup="disc" iconCollapsedGroup="disc"
                    iconExpandedTopGroup="chevronUp" iconGroupTopPosition="right"
                    iconCollapsedTopGroup="chevronDown">
                    <rich:panelMenuGroup label="Group 1">
                        <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 1.1"
                            action="#{PanelMenu.updateCurrent}">
                            <f:param name="current" value="Item 1.1" />
                        </rich:panelMenuItem>
                    </rich:panelMenuGroup>
                </rich:panelMenu>
                <rich:panel bodyClass="rich-laguna-panel-no-header">
                    <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
                        <h:outputText value="||#{PanelMenu.current}|| selected"
                            id="current" />
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                </rich:panel>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
<!-- added end -->
        <rich:panel>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="contentPanel">
                <a4j:include viewId="#{MyBacking.viewId}">
                    <f:param name="targetIdParam" value="content" />
                </a4j:include>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </rich:panel>
    </rich:page>
</f:view>
```

But if I remove the added `panelMenu` from this file and paste it into a separate tab in a `tabPanel` in an external jsp page which is then `a4j:include`d in the above `index.jsp`, when it's loaded, the `panelMenu` refuses to work (outputting nothing to the log or console) while in the other tab in my tab set there is a `rich:dataTable`. With the exact same code, but with the `dataTable` removed from the second tab, it all starts working again.

Here's the broken `a4j:include`d file with `panelMenu`:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" border="0" style="width: 100%">
    <rich:tabPanel switchType="client" rendered="true">
        <rich:tab styleClass="tab" label="Node Logs">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" border="0">
                <h:graphicImage value="/btn50.png" width="30" height="30"
                    alt="Logs" />
                <h:outputText value="log: #{MyBacking.chosenNode}"
                    styleClass="pageTitle" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:form id="form">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%">
                    <rich:panelMenu style="width:200px" mode="ajax"
                        iconExpandedGroup="disc" iconCollapsedGroup="disc"
                        iconExpandedTopGroup="chevronUp" iconGroupTopPosition="right"
                        iconCollapsedTopGroup="chevronDown">
                        <rich:panelMenuGroup label="Group 1">
                            <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 1.1"
                                action="#{PanelMenu.updateCurrent}">
                                <f:param name="current" value="Item 1.1" />
                            </rich:panelMenuItem>
                        </rich:panelMenuGroup>
                    </rich:panelMenu>
                    <rich:panel bodyClass="rich-laguna-panel-no-header">
                        <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
                            <h:outputText value="||#{PanelMenu.current}|| selected"
                                id="current" />
                        </a4j:outputPanel>
                    </rich:panel>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>

        </rich:tab>

        <rich:tab styleClass="tab" label="Docs">
            <rich:dataTable value="#{MyBacking.MyData}">
                <rich:column style="text-align:center" width="150px">
                </rich:column>
            </rich:dataTable>
        </rich:tab>
    </rich:tabPanel>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Thanks

Comment: most likely not a bug. Give us more code, and check your javascript console about details.

Comment: @Bozho, see added code and diag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem went away when I recast the taglib declarations as

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
```

instead of using `<% %>` tags (which aren't used with facelets anyway)

and installed `jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar`. No facelets jar was installed at all until this point!